# In ruby on linux, is there any way to get the siginfo_t data of a trapped signal?

Tags: ruby, linux, signals

I'm trying to figure out which process is sending a signal to one of my ruby scripts. I am able to trap the signal - is there any way to figure out which process sent it once I've done that? Normally, this would be in a siginfo_t structure passed to the signal handler - is this exposed in ruby?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation for signal handling in ruby, I would say that this information is not avalable.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Signal.html

Comment: The 1.9.1 source is consistent with this answer.  The sole appearance of siginfo_t in signal.c is surrounded by an #ifdef of the "does this platform have it?" flavor.  si_pid, the field containing the pid of the signaler, appears nowhere in the source.